# REST or SOAP? I have to choose one

Tags: rest, soap, service, web, media

I have to create a media service to prepare services to our other applications. the question is that our API should be REST or SOAP?

I read a lot of articles and materials that compare these two methods. every one has their own ideas about using one of them. someone believes that because of everyone switches their product to REST so its a good decision to use REST instead of SOAP. But I thought that the important thing is the purpose of product and base on the purpose we can choose between soap or REST.

Our service have no interaction with users. it just works with our local applications and it is important to me that my API be simple and useful. as I said the service brings media storage and management to other apps. I have experience in both of soap and rest but this time I can't choose one.

so what's your idea? SOAP or REST? In this type of projects actually!

Comment: it depends, what will be consuming the web service?

Comment: I said that service have to provide some functionality for storing and managing media of other applications such as videos and pictures.

Comment: Well what I am saying is not every technology has support for SOAP, for example Android. You have to use third party software or make the soap calls over http. They both have their stong suits though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for  `REST` - it is simpler and adds less overhead. Also, once your resources are clearly defined and delimited, the developer knows already how to interact with the API endpoints, without needing documentation or waiting for the creation of object interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose REST over SOAP no doubts, but from a consumer point of view SOAP is still easier to work with, given the wizards that exist already, which maps the WSDL types to proper types automagically, at least in Java and C# world.

It is very deceiving that REST is easier to work with. It is an open standard, much cleaner which leverages the HTTP protocol in a different way than SOAP Web Services does, and you have to understand that, because REST does not fit everyones business, specially if there is something already.

That said if you really want to know how the web works, be closed to the standards people are using, and rely less on wizards that create a lot of unnecessary code go with REST.

Answer (score -1):

REST, without question.

I have created API's using both protocols and REST is so much easier for the consumer, and much more flexible.

Google stopped supporting SOAP almost 4 years ago and uses REST and JSON exclusively now.

"partial response" in REST, where you get only the data you want, is huge.

Here is a useful doc on creating good REST API's:
http://info.apigee.com/Portals/62317/docs/web%20api.pdf

Comment: You've got to be kidding.  
Just using JSON instead of XML is far easier.
If you've used a REST API that is difficult, that is the fault of the implementation.  It can and should be so simple.

Comment: I first worked with REST/JSON and a custom MVC framwework for asp.net in March/2006, so I know what I am talking about, as for you, that´s the kind of comment from someone who does not really know what is talking about.

Comment: One bad experience does not make the rule.
Ask yourself why google dumped SOAP and now uses only REST and JSON.
I recently replaced a vendor's SOAP API with a new REST API and there is no comparison in the ease of use and flexibility with the REST API.
And yes, one good experience doesn't make the rule either.
But... SOAP is a dinosaur.

Comment: I don't think you got it. That´s when I first worked with REST, and it was not a bad experience quite the opposite. You still don't get what I said. Try to reference a REST webservice from visual studio and do the same for a SOAP based one.

Comment: Then you should say that REST is difficult with VisualStudio.
I find it easy to use, but I use PHP primarily.
However, I don't understand why it would be difficult.
Microsoft includes REST support in their .net framework.

Comment: I never said it was difficult did I? PHP hã, that says it all.